# Grub loader not present

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I dual booted Kali with Ubuntu 16.04, unfortunately it ended up deleting the partition.
I installed Kali on, meanwhile, I think the grub loader was installed on Kali. I am unable to use my system at all.
I tried boot-repair, the recommended function, it did not repair the grub.

Boot Info Summary: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9mz26p4Mhp/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (no boot, no grub) that I fixed by:

Read `man grub-install`

1. Boot from a Live USB key.
2. Open a terminal window <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-T</kbd>
3. Do `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`
4. **Note:** I also did `sudo grub-install /dev/sda1`, but I don't think it helped my problem.

Comment: i have  done this before,its still not working.Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I have repaired the grub after long hours of hunting. These are the steps I took

1. boot ubuntu from a live USB
2. Open terminal and run sudo su
3. dd if=/dev/zero of=/cowfile bs=1024 count=1024
4. mkfs.fat /cowfile
5. mv /cowfile /cow
   This creates a 1MB file with a FAT filesystem in it, and moves it to /cow, which is the “fake” path that grub-mkconfig can’t find. With it in place, /cow looks like an empty FAT partition to grub-mkconfig, and will be quietly ignored.
6. sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
7. grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda

   Finally update grub boot loader and done!
8. sudo update-grub